# JS: Script for sticky navbar not running

Tags: javascript, navbar, offset

For some reason on my webpage, the javascript for a sticky navbar isn't running at all. Here is the [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uh6e88n3/). The navbar (in bright orange) runs across the top of the page - at the base of header. The script is set to make the navbar visible after the user scrolls past a point and then past a further point, it is meant to make it fixed to the top of the viewport with the help of `.offset().top;`.

I've tried out the exact same script in a similar implementation and it works. Would appreciate anyone's help pointing out the glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the z-index in your html Layout

```
<header>
        <div class="mainheader">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logoinner.png">
            <img class="detail1" src="images/detail1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="subheader"></div>

        <div id="menu-wrapper">
          <nav id="menu">
            <div class="menu">
              <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                  <img class="logoflag" src="images/logoflag.png">
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>

</header>

<div class="contentwrap">
.....
</div>
```

You only set the z-index of the menu wrapper div but the z-index of the header was still smaller than the z-index of your div class="contentwrap". So just increase the z-index of the header and it should work.

here is a fixed fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uh6e88n3/6/

Comment: It works but am still trying to figure the changes you made exaclty. In the script, you added a console.log, you also added a z-index, apart from adding  z-index to the header. Is that basically it? but the change in the header's css alone fixes the issue.

Comment: Sry you are wright the header css is all you need i will revert the other changes and add a new fiddle link, they where just for testing on my end  :)

Comment: no issues there - and thanks for spotting the glitch in my code.